# Mac Eclipse has an error when I write a Java code

Tags: java, macos

Everytime I write a Java code on mac, it says it can't run the codes. (My current java version is 1.8.0_111 whereas eclipse's jre version is 1.8.0_66. I'm not sure if it matters.) Previously, Eclipse worked pretty well, but it suddenly doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: what would I do with your photo ? Post your code here.

Comment: What error is it actually giving? All you've done is screenshot the red

Comment: Well, the code that you have there is invalid. You can't put statements into class bodies directly. You need a static void main method if you want to **run** something! In other words: the tool is telling you that your source code doesn't compile; and stuff that doesn't compile will **never** run. And did **never** run in the past.

Comment: Take an online course on java before you do any more coding: http://mooc.fi/courses/2013/programming-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

You have a System.out.println directly in the class body. If you want to run that line of code you need to add it to a main method.